# Show HTML mark-up in JFrame or open Browser

Tags: java, html, browser, jframe

I am writing a Java program that creates HTML code.

What's the best/easiest possibility to have a preview of the code?

- Show the code in the `JFrame`: How can I do this?
- Open the windows browser with the created File? Is this possible?
- A totally different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are quite easy to do. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) is a page from the Java tutorial that shows how to display HTML in Swing (you'd use a `file:` URL to display the contents of a file.) You can display a URL in an external browser using Java 6's `Desktop` class:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("file://myfile.html"));
```

Alternately, save the data in a file with the `*.html` extension and use

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("myfile.html"));
```

Comment: +1, but 1) [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) requires an ..`URI`. 2) [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) a `File`. 3)  I heard `browse` only worked with web based URLs, not `file:` based.  4) Aside: Depending on the scope (limited) and nature (HTML 3.2) of the HTML, I'd tend to go for the `JEditorPane`.  No file required to preview!

Comment: I used `.open(new File("src/media/example.html"))`

Comment: @AndrewThompson -- thanks, I edited and cleaned up a lot of  that sloppiness.